# How to say "do you have"

Tags: word-choice, english-to-japanese

This may sound strange, but say you're talking to a friend on the phone, or an equivalent. You want to ask if they have a new game or say, got the new character in a game. I realise you can ask 'have you received', but is there any way besides  持つ and ある? Like a verb to 'own' or to 'possess'?

If I'm not making sense, say if I asked you if you had a car. Would I just say あなたは車がある？ What about a new character in a game? How would I say 'do you own him' or 'have you got/received him yet'?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose these could be used for gaming. Remember to use the right tense.

> 仲間に入れる - make a friend out of
>   仲間に加える - to add into your group of friends
>   手に入れる　- often used when finding items in game
>  
>   見つかる / 見つける  - to find/be found　transitive/intransitive
>   ゲットする - english loanword for "get" suru verb
>   プレーする　- english loanfor for "to play" hear it used in sports a lot. Maybe for videogames too

There are a lot of loanwords in both videosgames and sports.

more general words for purchase/import/buy

> 購入 - purchase
>   輸入 - import
>   買う　- buy

for cars

> 新車 - new car
>   外車 - import car

Answer (score 3):

> you're talking to a friend on the phone... if I asked you if you had a car. Would I just say あなたは車がある？

I would say 「[車]{くるま} [持]{も}ってる？」 or 「車 ある？」

> What about a new character in a game? How would I say 'do you own him' or 'have you got/received him yet'?

「XX手{て}に入{い}れた?」 would be fine, but to sound more casual I would say 「XX [取]{と}った？」 「XX [取]{と}れた？」 「XX ゲットした?」 or maybe 「XX もう持ってる？」

> You want to ask if they have a new game

I would say 「XX (もう)買った？」 or 「XX もう持ってる？」

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more verbs that are related to having, receiving, and owning.

These ones are common:

くれる - to give (usually to speaker)
もらう - to receive (from somebody)
ゲットする - to get, to obtain
受{う}ける - to get, to receive
得{え}る - to acquire, to get
取{と}る - to take
含{ふく}む  to have, to include
抱{かか}える - to hold/carry in/under the arms, to have (problems, debts, etc.)

There ones may be more rare or formal:

達{たっ}する - to reach, to get to
擁{よう}する - to have, to possess
有{ゆう}する - to own, to have
所有{しょゆう}する - to own, to possess (property)

Also, 持つ has an advantage over ある because you can leave out the topic/subject without changing the meaning.

> 車がある。 There is a car.
>   私は車がある。 I have a car. (As for me, there is a car.)
>   （私は）車を持ってる。 (I) have a car.

Answer (score 0):

Like Saitama and Darcinon mentioned, there are several expressions you can use for different situations here, depending on the context. I don't think there's a universal answer here though.

If you want to ask "do you have/own a car?" 
The most natural way of asking would be

> 車を持っている？

In theory you could use 持っている　with the game character as well, but in that context these terms might be better.

> 大乱闘スマッシュブラザーズでワリオをゲットした？
>   or
>   もうワリオを手に入れた？